# Как происходит работа распределенного приложения?

Tags: highload, веб-программирование

Допустим есть большой и сложный проект, который будет в то же время высоконагруженным. Ненужно быть папой Карло, чтоб понять что 1 сервер его не потянет.

Вопрос собственно вот в чём: как быть в такой ситуации? Попробую сам частично ответить на свой же вопрос и попрошу вас либо всё перечеркнуть, либо поправить.

Приложение буду называть системой. Понятно как систему разбить на 2 части. На одной машине ставим сервер БД (в данном конкретном случае пусть это будет бесплатный MySQL Server). На другой - web-сервер (Пусть для наглядности Apache с подключенным модулем php), на котором будет исполняться сам код. Но что делать если сервер должен будет принимать по 10000 запросов каждую секунду. Понятно, что код надо оптимизировать. В БД по-хорошему работать с хранимыми процедурами, разумеется должно быть кэширование и т.д.

Как быть, что делать, куда копать если нужно сделать так чтоб один исходный код выполнялся на нескольких машинах? И как быть, если сервер БД не справляется и нужно сделать так, чтобы один источник данных обрабатывало несколько серверов БД?

Понимаю, что в ответ можно книгу написать и не одну, но буду безмерно благодарен хотя более-менее развернутому ответу.

Comment: "Понимаю, что в ответ можно книгу написать и не одну," -- да вы оптимист...

Comment: неужели никто хотя бы несколько предложений написать хотя бы о принципах реализации сего?

Comment: Ну вот ссылка (одна из) про производительность http-серверов: http://joeandmotorboat.com/2009/01/03/nginx-vs-yaws-vs-mochiweb-web-server-performance-deathmatch-part-2/

Comment: да я не о производительности спрашивал, а о том как делают, чтоб один код исполнялся на несколких машинах

Comment: Ну разнести sql-сервер и web-сервер вообще никаких проблем. Что ещё нужно разносить?

Comment: А что может помешать одному и тому же коду исполняться на нескольких машинах ?  Просто такой код должен **уметь** синхронизировать работу своих частей на разных машинах.

Comment: @avp атомы в erlang'е?

Comment: @avp, а какими способами это достигается? скрипиты через curl общаются друг с другом?

Comment: Я думаю, что на ПХП (Вы видимо говорите о скриптах ПХП) ничего хорошего не получится. 

Да, компоненты должны обмениваться сообщениями по сети. Думаю, что надо попытаться разнести распараллеливание СУБД (например посмотрите Oracle RAC) и прикладной части. 

Если говорить об эффективной прикладной части, то ее основу IMHO должны составлять специализированные демоны, протокол обмена тоже специализирован под конкретную задачу (скорее всего сделан на смеси  UDP и TCP).

Интерфейс между демонами и "исполнителями" на одном узле скорее всего через shared memory.

Что-то в таком духе.

Comment: Как простой вариант, у Вас много "**несвязанных**" между собой запросов (в основном на выборку) к общей базе. 

В подобном случае синхронизация (постоянная) не нужна. СУБД ставите на один сервер (или кластер для надежности) помощнее с хорошей системой доступа к данным.

Разбрасываете HTTP сервера по разным машинам, они обращаются к одной базе на сервере по сети, балансируете запросы HTTP клиентов сетевыми средствами.

Comment: такой протокол есть и он называется MPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем про memcache (и про его кластеризацию), GFS, кластеризация MYSQL.
Так же, читаем про организацию **livejournal** - http://www.livejournal.com/doc/server/

Так же, можно обратить внимание на CDN технологию.
Почитайте про eAccelerator и xCache (для кэша запиленного в байт-код PHP).....

Обязательно прочтите принцип работы nginx и apache (apache - backend; nginx - frontend ).

Ну и , наверное, самое основное - откажитесь от прямой верстки HTML кода.

Comment: "откажитесь от прямой верстки HTML кода", то есть html не просто выводить и в него встраивать php, а полностью генерировать html? я правильно Вас понимаю?

Answer (score 0):

Вы разработчик или айтишник/админ? Если разработчик - то не ломайте голову и пусть голову ломают айтишники. Если все написано по человечески в трехслойной архитектуре, то есть данные в нормальном СУБД поддерживающем кластеризацию (сомневаюсь что бесплатный MySQL поддерживают кластеризацию), а странички смотрят наружу через нормальный веб-сервер, то айтишник среднего уровня агрессивности сваяет вам конфигурацию серверов на бумажке за полчаса. А дальше это только вопрос бюджета - бюджета нехилого, поскольку 10 тыс. сессий это много.

Comment: При таком взгляде на проблему, я бы ответил автору, что задающему подобные вопросы на форумах, разработка системы на 10000 запросов в секунду в настоящее время не грозит.


Скорее всего автор просто любопытствует, а что делают если ...